Wacom cth-470 doesnt work porperly
I have a Wacom cth-470 tablet.
The device is identified as
056a:00de   CTH-470 Bamboo Capture/Manga        3.3 2.6.30*†    0.18

The former information came from
https://github.com/linuxwacom/input-wacom/wiki/Device-IDs
I plug the device onto Ubuntu 20.04 and it seems to work fine, but when I stop using the pen to use the mouse for a second it does weird stuff like zooming etc. I know it is an old device but I still have the Driver CD that came with it. I installed the drivers on Windows 10 in my old PC and everything works fine.
By the way, when in Ubuntu the two buttons in the tablet nearest to the middle line don't work. When trying to set a keybind, I click the button just below the middle line but it tries to set the keybind to the lowest button.
Is there a way to make this thing work properly?
